# How to avoid globals in Go with julien schmidt's router?

Tags: go

I am developing a RESTful API with Go but owing to app configuration, authentication etc I have quite a few global variables.

I am using Julien Schmidt's httprouter because of popular recommendation and am looking for a feasible way to avoid global variables.

Here is some of the code.

I am using a middleware for authenticating a user using gorrila/securecookie.

```
func AuthMiddleware(handler httprouter.Handle, isLoggedIn bool) httprouter.Handle {
    return func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, ps httprouter.Params) {if isLoggedIn {
            currUser, err := GetCurrentUser(r)

            if currUser.Username != "" {
                handler(w, r, ps)
                return
            }

            responseWriter(w, false, "User not logged in", nil)
            return
        }
        handler(w, r, ps)
    }
}
```

After this, I want to be able to use the currUser object inside the handler that the request is forwarded to such as this one instead of calling GetCurrentUser once again

```
func foobar(w http.ResponseWriter, _ *http.Request, _ httprouter.Params) {
    var currQuestion CurrQuestions

    err = Db.db.Raw("SELECT * FROM users WHERE U.user_id = ?", currUser.UserID).Find(&currQuestion).Error
    if err != nil {
        responseWriter(w, false, "Internal Server Error", "")
        return
    }
    responseWriter(w, true, "", GameData{})
}
```

Comment: Use locals instead? Without any code or any details this question is unanswerable.

Comment: I understand your point, and I have added some of the relevant code.

Comment: Why don't you just pass the user object to the handler?

Comment: There's absolutely no reason one should use, or assume, global variables, in the code you've included.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the context package. Values stored in context are only accessible in the current controller. In your middleware (at the end) do the following:

```
ctx := context.WithValue(r.Context(), "User", user)
r = r.WithContext(ctx)
handler(w, r, ps)
```

Now you can fetch this value in you handler:

```
user, ok := r.Context().Value("User").(<type of your user struct>)
```

The string "User" is the key that is used to save the value. You can change it any way you like, but a const is a good idea.

if `ok` is `true`, the user has been fetched and is the correct type. If `ok` is `false`, the user was not set or it has the wrong type.